# JasperReports JRXML Create parameter/variable with static data

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using a Ireport and trying to create report parameter as hashmap with my data. I don't understand what can I write in default expression of parameter. 
I wrote:

```
java.util.Мap.put("field_name","value").
```

But it doesn't work. There are no HashMap type of parameter.

I know how to create  List - one row of static table:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello", "Another Value")
```

But I don't understand how create many rows.

Comment: Know It works put("field","value") for hashmap. But I still don't know how to create many fields and many values of fields.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue? Facing simillar task..